# ActiveMQ Spring CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE not working

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I can't seem to figure this out...
This works perfectly in JAVA:

```
// Create a Session
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE); // << means we have to acknowledge that we processed it!
```

But when I create a Spring Bean, I cannot get the CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE to work.  It seems that it's auto-acknowledging all messages.

```
<bean id="testListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" lazy-init="true">
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="MyQueue" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="testListener" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="concurrency" value="2"/>
</bean>
```

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The DMLC in spring has transactions enabled in your config, while in your Java example, you have transactions disabled. Transactions overrides any acknowledge modes. So, choose if you should go with transactions or client ack since you cannot pick both.

Comment: I'll try that again.  This is just the latest iteration of many combinations of "stuff" to try to make this work.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.  We go ti working (sort of) by using a transaction manager ans throwing a runtime exception, but I want to force the acknowledgement in the code.  This causes all other scenarios to be un-acknowledge, including catastrophic failure of the system.